# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while sorting an array

Tags: java, exception

I am an absolute beginner to Java. Recently i started to write a code in Java to sort the 5 elements of an array. The user will input the array elements. It complies the code and runs the program. but as soon as i finish inputting the array elemts, the program crashes!
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr;
        arr = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 elemnts in the array");
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        int temp;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            temp = arr[i+1];
            for(int j=i+1; j>=0; j--)
            {
                if(arr[i] > temp)
                {
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

it throws an error which is something like:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
i just cannot read and understand the error!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)? I suggest you do that, and read the [arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Next, think about the value of `i+1` across all the values of `i` that you'll be using...

Comment: Thanks, I found it useful :)

Comment: I'd also get used to reading the error. It seems overwhelming at first, but it *should* tell you exactly what you need to do. The phrase `Main.Java:16` tells you the line the error is on, and the name of the exception, `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` tells you that the number in the array that you're trying to access doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    temp = arr[i+1];
    //         ^^^
    //   Right here!
    ...
}
```

when `i` is equal to `4`, `i+1` is `5`, which is past the end of the array.

This kind of error is so common that it has its own name: it is called [*Off By One Error*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). When you see `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in a loop, the first thing you look for is this sort of error.

Answer (score 2):

Your array has a length of 5, indexes start at 0. That means your maximum index is 4 but you try to access your array with the index 5 in your for loop:

```
 temp = arr[i+1];
```